# xdmp:document-load Xquery Command

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

When I ingest a csv file containing multiple xml records using mlcp, I use an options file to change the desired ML output from one csv document into multiple xml documents. How do I script this using xdmp:document-load command within the query console?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `xdmp:document-load` provides an option for that. Instead, use [`xdmp:document-get`](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-get), split with XPath, then [`xdmp:document-insert`](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-get).

Comment: There's important details to understand on this section as well: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ingestion/formats